# Automatic axis for graph

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a SQL query in MS Access that produces data for a bar graph. This data contains a number and month name in "01 Jan" format. The SQL is created to get the data for the last 5 months including the current month. The code is not working since new year and it can work if I change the span of 5 months into 3 months. I believe this is a date formatting issue but I can't seem to figure it out. I am new to SQL. Could anyone please help me. The code is:

```
SELECT (Format([INITIATION DATE],"mm")) & " " & (Format([INITIATION DATE],"mmm")) AS Expr1, Sum([Data].[Count Area 1]) AS SumOfCount
FROM [Data]
GROUP BY (Format([INITIATION DATE], "mm")) & " " & (Format([INITIATION DATE], "mmm")), (Format([INITIATION DATE], "yyyy")) & (Format([INITIATION DATE], "mm"))
HAVING ((((Format([INITIATION DATE],"yyyy")) & (Format([INITIATION DATE],"mm")))>=Format(DateAdd("yyyy",0,Date()),"yyyy") & Format(DateAdd("m",-5,Date()),"mm")));
```

The end result I am looking for is [image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  If you are only storing the month, how do you know what year the month belongs to.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the kind reply. I thought that Group By clause will sort the Data in 202001 format, thereby getting the year and then 'having' clause makes sure that the data is only up to last 5 months. The problem here is that this code will be wrong for 1st 5 months of the year as the year value is not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `WHERE` clause, not a `HAVING` clause.  And you want the logic on the *date* not the month:

```
SELECT (Format([INITIATION DATE],"mm")) & " " & (Format([INITIATION DATE],"mmm")) AS Expr1,
        Sum([Data].[Count Area 1]) AS SumOfCount
FROM [Data]
WHERE [INITIATION DATE] >= DATEADD("mm", -5, DATE())
GROUP BY (Format([INITIATION DATE], "mm")) & " " & (Format([INITIATION DATE], "mmm"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression below substracts 5 months from the month, but doesn't touch the year

```
Format(DateAdd("yyyy",0,Date()),"yyyy") & Format(DateAdd("m",-5,Date()),"mm")))
```

hence you're asking for all dates bigger than '202011'

I do not have MSAccess but it seems that you can have this as the last row

```
HAVING ((((Format([INITIATION DATE],"yyyymm"))>=Format(DateAdd("m",-5,Date()),"yyyymm")));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. This worked. However, as Gordon mentioned I need to find a way to figure out the year since the graph I created was assuming Nov and Dec as part of this year instead of last year.

Comment: @TJ0007 . . . Do not filter in the `HAVING` clause if you can filter in the `WHERE` (i.e. before aggregation).  Do not convert dates to strings for comparison.  This code probably works, but it is not a good example of how to write the logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, you are correct. My main goal was to explain why his code didn't work past new year.